How to stretch content on print page using flying saucer
I need to put an image to the bottom of last pdf page (but above page counter which is in bottom-right page margin box).
@page {
   size: A4 landscape;
   margin: 20mm 10mm 20mm 20mm;
   @bottom-right {
      content: element(counterDiv);
   }
}

.div-to-stretch {
   height: 100%;
}
...
<div>another content</div>

<div class="div-to-stretch">
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,${data}"/>
</div>

I'm not very good at css so my idea is to use a div with this image inside, stretch the div to the whole page by height and align the image to the bottom of the div. But I've failed on the first step - stretch something to the whole print page.
Is there any way to stretch the element? Should I use some another approach to put the image to the bottom of the page?
I've tried to stretch whole html body to the page like this
body, html {height: 100%;}

Also tried to position the div as a footer using
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;

Also tried
position: fixed; 

but got the div on every page
